# плАнерная или планЁнрная

Tags: орфоэпия

Тот, кто планирует - плановщик, от слова ПЛАН, а как будет правильно - улица план**Ё**рная или пл**А**нерная?

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от значения (основных — два) слова *план* возможны определения: плановый или планарный, но никак не *планерный* (от планера или планёра). Варианты слова — Планерная, Планёрная — равноправны, но, то ли с массовым уклонением на письме от использования Ё, то ли с утратой традиций или уходом людей, первоначальное название искажается и вызывает вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

В Москве до недавнего времени считалось правильным План**ё**рная - станция метро в первую очередь. 
Связано с планёром, не с планом.

При этом в массе говорили Пл**а**нерная. Сейчас, вроде, повсеместно перешли на этот вариант вплоть до его кодификации:

- [Планёрная улица](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%28%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%29)
- [Планерный ручей](http://moscow.gramota.ru/dict.shtml#p)

Хотя мне по-прежнему вариант без Ё не нравится.

Насчет улицы вообще - не знаю. А в каком городе?